# How to install Ubuntu 12.10 on already i.e preinstalled win 7 or win8 PC?

Tags: 12.04

How to install Ubuntu 12.10 on already i.e preinstalled win 7 or win8 PC?

Please tell  me with out deletion of my files..nothing should happen to my PC files which i installed on WIN 7 or 8

Answer (score 0):

See the [Community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) for Windows dual boot.